# type of syscall a process or program is making

Tags: linux, system-calls, system-administration, devops

I am trying to find how many different type of syscalls a process or program is making. I know that I can do following to get total number of calls for each syscall as below.

```
strace -c cat abc.txt
```

The output of above is command.

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  -nan    0.000000           0        10           read
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           write
  -nan    0.000000           0        12           open
  -nan    0.000000           0        14           close
  -nan    0.000000           0        12           fstat
  -nan    0.000000           0        28           mmap
  -nan    0.000000           0        16           mprotect
  -nan    0.000000           0         3           munmap
  -nan    0.000000           0         3           brk
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           ioctl
  -nan    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           execve
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           fcntl
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           getdents
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           statfs
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  -nan    0.000000           0         2         1 futex
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                   116         2 total
```

As you can see that it returns the total number of syscalls made which is `116`. I only need to know how many different type syscalls were made which is `22` in this case.

Is there a way to do that in one line using `strace` ?

Comment: Isn't what you wrote one line?

Comment: That one line returns the all syscall and their counts. I only need total number of different syscalls made. Eg. 10 different syscall type among 1000 total syscalls made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output to `wc -l` to get the number of lines in the statistics. Since the statistics are written to standard error, you'll need to do some redirection for this.

```
strace -c cat abc.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null | wc -l
```

You'll also need to subtract 4 from this, because of the header, total, and divider lines.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  Thats what I wanted :)